# How to convert text file column into csv file single row using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I have text file which look like this:

[textfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YLVa.png)

now I want to convert that text file in csv file single row

The outcome would look like:
[csv_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwooD.png)

Comment: A text file should read as text and a csv file is also a text file. Please show them as copyable **TEXT** and not as images.

Answer (score 1):

You coud `zip` the `split`ed lines and then `",".join` over the sum of the components:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as fin,\
     open("file.csv", "w") as fout:
    col1, col2 = zip(*(line.rstrip().split() for line in fin))
    fout.write(",".join(col1 + col2))
```

If needed, add a `"\n"` to the end of the row.

If you have much more columns than 2 you could use `chain`:

```
from itertools import chain

with open("file.txt", "r") as fin,\
     open("file.csv", "w") as fout:
    zipped = zip(*(line.rstrip().split() for line in fin))
    fout.write(",".join(chain(*zipped)))
```

---

Re comment: Use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to chop the input into chunks, and then use the procedure above on the chunks:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

with open("file.txt", "r") as fin,\
     open("file.csv", "w") as fout:
    for key, group in groupby(fin, key=lambda line: bool(line.strip())):
        if key:
            zipped = zip(*(line.rstrip().split() for line in group))
            fout.write(",".join(chain(*zipped)) + "\n")
```

Out put for `file.txt`

```
dq1    sp1    tq1    rp1
dq2    sp2    tq2    rp2
dp3    sp3    tq3    rp3
dp4    sp4    tq4    rp4

1      2      3      4
5      6      7      8
9      10     11     12
13     14     15     16
```

in `file.csv` is

```
dq1,dq2,dp3,dp4,sp1,sp2,sp3,sp4,tq1,tq2,tq3,tq4,rp1,rp2,rp3,rp4
1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15,4,8,12,16
```

Comment: suppose if I have 4 column and 4 column than how to configure see the text file

Answer (score 0):

You could use `T` or `transpose()` to switch orientation of your `DataFrame` - Getting rid of `headers` and `index` set them to `false`:

```
df.T.to_csv('result.csv',header=False, index=False)
```

#### Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['db1','db2','db3','db4','db5','db6'])

df.T.to_csv('result.csv',header=False, index=False)
```

#### Output

```
db1,db2,db3,db4,db5,db6\r\n
```

Answer (score 0):

First we will import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Second we will read the txt.file:

```
df = pd.read_csv("x.txt")
```

Third we will make this df -> csv with Transpose (to switch column orientation to row orientation) and header = False (will drop column names row)

```
df.T.to_csv('result.csv', header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

A csv is also a text file. You could simply read the text file as follows:

```
with open("in.txt", "r") as f:
    columns = f.read().splitlines()
```

And write a new one:

```
with open("out.csv", "w") as out:
    out.write(",".join(columns)) # "," is default, you can use any sep
```

Comment: suppose i have two column in txt file than same i have to do